# Cant type password in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: login-screen

Recently I updated my ubuntu system from 18.04 to 20.04.01. When I try restart my pc and it shows option to enter password. When I try to enter the password the password field remains blank no matter how many keys I enter.

Comment: Please do not duplicate questions here.  Add on to your original question if you have something else to add:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285816/cant-type-my-password-after-upgrading-my-ubuntu-system-from-18-04-to-20-04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't type my password after upgrading my ubuntu system from 18.04 to 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285816/cant-type-my-password-after-upgrading-my-ubuntu-system-from-18-04-to-20-04)